# Find the remainder from the division of $3^{2017}-1$ into $3^{403}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

Here is an interesting problem:

Find the remainder from the division of $3^{2017}-1$ into $3^{403}-1$

Comment: Since you are a fairly new user, I would first of all like to welcome you to our stack exchange! Secondly, I suggest that you put some effort, thoughts or even any knowledge you have over the subject of your questions. This way, your posts will be way better well taken !

Comment: **Hint** $\bmod n-1\!:\ n\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, f(n)\equiv f(1)\ $ for any polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$3^{2017} = \Big(3^{403}\Big)^5 \cdot 3^2$$

Answer (score 3):

$$3^{403}\equiv 1\pmod{3^{403}-1}$$
 Raise to the power 5. You get,

$$3^{2015}\equiv 1\pmod{3^{403}-1}$$

$$3^{2017}\equiv 9\pmod{3^{403}-1}$$

$$3^{2017}-1\equiv 8\pmod{3^{403}-1}$$

So the remainder is 8.

Answer (score 2):

If $n=3^{403}$, you are dividing $9n^5-1$ by $n-1$.

But $9n^5-1=9(n^5-1)+8$ and the remainder is $8$.